# Неправильная обработка сигнала с клавиатуры

Tags: qt5, qtcreator, qml, qtquick

На форме qml присутствует виджет `SpinBox`, по дефолту у него значение от -800 до 800.

Мне нужно, чтобы ввод цифр с клавиатуры передавал в С++ его текущее значение. Но проблема в том, что он его передаёт всегда 800 несмотря на то, что я ввел 123.

То-есть, прямо говоря, мне нужно сразу передавать текущее значение с SpinBox'а при каждом нажатии на цифру.

Вот код обработчика:

```
Keys.onReleased: {
    if(event.key === Qt.Key_1) {
        m_EQDrive.trackDEC(spBox_maxRate2.value * 15)
        event.accepted = true;
    }
    if(event.key === Qt.Key_2) {
        m_EQDrive.trackDEC(spBox_maxRate2.value * 15)
        event.accepted = true;
    }
    if(event.key === Qt.Key_3) {
        m_EQDrive.trackDEC(spBox_maxRate2.value * 15)
        event.accepted = true;
    }
}
```

Вот код всего `SpinBox`:

```
SpinBox {
    id: spBox_maxRate2
    x: 154
    y: 127
    width: 138
    height: 42

    from: -800
    to: 800
    value: 800

    editable: true
    wheelEnabled: true
    wrap: true

    Material.accent: "#2196F3"
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    Material.foreground: "white"

    Keys.onReleased: {
        if(event.key === Qt.Key_1) {
            m_EQDrive.trackDEC(spBox_maxRate2.value * 15)
            event.accepted = true;
        }
        if(event.key === Qt.Key_2) {
            m_EQDrive.trackDEC(spBox_maxRate2.value * 15)
            event.accepted = true;
        }
        if(event.key === Qt.Key_3) {
            m_EQDrive.trackDEC(spBox_maxRate2.value * 15)
            event.accepted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

`m_EQDrive` - класс куда будет передаваться значение.

Comment: UPD:

Пока кнопка Enter не будет нажата то новое значение не будет передано в класс, а нужно чтобы при каждом вводе цифры он передавал новую цифру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему:

```
SpinBox {
    id: spBox_MaxRate

    anchors.centerIn: parent

    from: -800
    to: 800
    value: 800

    editable: true
    wheelEnabled: true
    wrap: true

    Material.accent: "#2196F3"
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    Material.foreground: "white"

    //Сигнал по изменению значений
    onValueChanged: {
        spinBoxValue = spBox_MaxRate.value * 15
    }

    focus: true

    //Сигналы на нажатие кнопок
    Keys.onReleased: {
        if(event.key === Qt.Key_0) { //кнопка 0
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = false
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = true
            event.accepted = true;
        }

        if(event.key === Qt.Key_1) { //кнопка 1
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = false
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = true
            event.accepted = true;
        }

        if(event.key === Qt.Key_2) { //кнопка 2
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = false
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = true
            event.accepted = true;
        }

        if(event.key === Qt.Key_3) { //кнопка 3
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = false
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = true
            event.accepted = true;
        }

        if(event.key === Qt.Key_4) { //кнопка 4
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = false
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = true
            event.accepted = true;
        }

        if(event.key === Qt.Key_5) { //кнопка 5
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = false
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = true
            event.accepted = true;
        }

        if(event.key === Qt.Key_6) { //кнопка 6
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = false
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = true
            event.accepted = true;
        }

        if(event.key === Qt.Key_7) { //кнопка 7
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = false
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = true
            event.accepted = true;
        }

        if(event.key === Qt.Key_8) { //кнопка 8
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = false
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = true
            event.accepted = true;
        }

        if(event.key === Qt.Key_9) { //кнопка 9
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = false
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = true
            event.accepted = true;
        }

        if(event.key === Qt.Key_Backspace) {
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = false
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = true

            event.accepted = true;
        }

        if(event.key === Qt.Key_Delete) {
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = false
            spBox_MaxRate.focus = true
            event.accepted = true;
        }
    }
    //===================

    //Выделение значений мышкой
    contentItem: TextInput {
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
        selectByMouse: true
        text: parent.textFromValue(parent.value, parent.locale)
        font.pointSize: 13
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        color: "white"
        selectedTextColor: "black"
        selectionColor: "white"
    }

    onFocusChanged: {
        console.log("Focus changed")

        //Вывод значения когда фокус виджета будет в true
        if(spBox_MaxRate.focus === true) {
            spinBoxValue = spBox_MaxRate.value * 15
            console.log("Value: " + spinBoxValue)
        }
    }
}
```

`spinBoxValue` это переменная `property real spinBoxValue`